# python tkinter dice rolling

Tags: python, tkinter

i was working on making a board game using python tkinter but i am having trouble working out how to add the dice rolls up i have a code for it in there but it failed so i was hoping someone more experienced could look at it and help me out here is my code here ( it is taken from a much larger code)

```
from tkinter import*
from random import randint
r = randint
l=Label
b=Button
def grid():
    roll1t = 0
    t=Tk()

    def roll1():
        roll1 = (r(1, 6))
        l(t, text=roll1).grid(column=3,row=7)
        roll1t += roll1
        print(roll1t)
    b(t, text='p1 roll',width=9 ,height=2, borderwidth=5, relief='raised', 
    command=roll1).grid(column=2,row=7, pady=(20, 20))
grid()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please give a detailed description of what goes wrong, instead of "it failed", thus the community can help you better

Comment: I think the main issue with your code is that the function roll1 does not return a value, and you try to add roll1t to the function, thus adding a return to roll1 an changing roll1 to roll1() in the second last line should make it run - however I do not really understand the desired behaviour

Comment: the problem is that when i click the button it will not add roll1 to roll1t i can change it slightly to add = before + but this only makes it turn roll1t in to roll1 rather than totalling all the roll1s ( what i want it to do is add the random number between 1 and 6 to roll1t every time it generates a new number for example if the first number generated is 4 and then the next time i press the button the number is 6 roll1t should = 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for trying to answer this question but it turns out that i just needed to create global variables (thanks to  Benjamin James Drury for suggesting that) because otherwise i cant edit the information outside the loop hear is the code hear.

```
from tkinter import*
from random import randint
r = randint
l=Label
b=Button
def grid():
    global roll1t
    roll1t = 0
    t=Tk()

    def roll1():
        global roll1t
        roll1 = (r(1, 6))
        l(t, text=roll1).grid(column=3,row=7)
        roll1t += roll1
        print(roll1t)
    b(t, text='p1 roll',width=9 ,height=2, borderwidth=5, relief='raised', command=roll1).grid(column=2,row=7, pady=(20, 20))
grid()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `roll1t + roll1` to either:

`roll1t += roll1` or `roll1t = roll1t + roll1`

They do the same thing, just the first is shorter than the second.

Comment: i have already tried this and all it dose it turn roll1t in to roll1 i want roll1t to add the totals of roll1

Comment: I'm afraid you are incorrect. If roll1t is becoming equal to roll1 then there is an issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: i have edited the code to what you said and now this error is coming up every time i press the button i was hoping you could help

Comment: >>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 119, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\alex\OneDrive\my python programs\stacks over flow questions.py", line 13, in roll1
    roll1t += roll1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'roll1t' referenced before assignment

Comment: There are lots of issues with your code. You should make roll1t global and remove the roll1 function from grid to make it its own function as roll1t is not in scope unless grid has been called.

Comment: thanks for the tip of making it global i have edited my code and the working code is now below